# Add logging provider using configuration only

Tags: .net, logging, configuration

My `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "Console": {
      "FormatterName": "simple",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "SingleLine": false,
        "IncludeScopes": true,
        "TimestampFormat": "HH:mm:ss.fff ",
        "UseUtcTimestamp": false
      }
    }
  },
}
```

However, the Console-provider only works, if I also register it code respectively

`builder.Logging.AddConsole();`

Judging from the [this Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter) I would've assumed, that it should be possible to actually **add** a logging provider using configuration only.

> In this article, you will learn about console log formatters.
> The sample source code demonstrates how to:
> Select a registered formatter to use
>
> - Either through code, **or** configuration

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

I find it kind of counter intuitive that you can't add a log provider, unless you have it hard-coded to begin with.

Comment: The article mentions replacing the `ConfigureLogging` call, which was not actually used in the example. I'd suggest trying to replace `AddSystemdConsole` or `AddSimpleConsole` with `builder.Logging.AddConfiguration(builder.Configuration);`so that the builder looks at your configuration.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, the answer addresses my actual question in that "You can configure logging, i.e. log levels for each provider, filtering out messages, etc., but the actual providers must be assigned in code."